# GCC #pragma to stop compilation

Tags: gcc

Is there a GCC pragma directive that will stop, halt, or abort the compilation process?

I am using GCC 4.1, but I would want the pragma to be available in GCC 3.x versions also.

Comment: We might be able to provide a better answer if you tell us why you want compilation to stop.

Comment: Is the constraint on GCC 3-4.1 still relevant?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You probably want `#error`:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ g++ -Wall -DGoOn -o stopthis stopthis.cpp
$ ./stopthis

Hello, world

$ g++ -Wall -o stopthis stopthis.cpp

stopthis.cpp:7:6: error: #error I had enough
```

##### File *stopthis.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
  std::cout << "Hello, world\n";
  #ifndef GoOn
    #error I had enough
  #endif
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A limitation here is `#error` can't be used inside a macro, though the question is vague as to the purpose.

Comment: I thought this too, however my GCC (4.9) isn't stopping with an error, it carries on, obviously it doesn't compile but it doesn't halt, is this a bug or can you confirm?

Answer (score 22):

I do not know about a `#pragma`, but `#error` should do what you want:

```
#error Failing compilation
```

It will terminate compilation with the error message "Failing compilation".

Answer (score 13):

This works:

```
 #include <stophere>
```

GCC stops when it can't find the include file. I wanted GCC to stop if [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14) was not supported.

```
 #if __cplusplus<201300L
   #error need g++14
   #include <stophere>
#endif
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  It prevents the compiler from continuing and potentially spamming lots of unhelpful errors that occur after the #error.  Those later errors may be misleading to some since they are likely just side effects of the first error.

Answer (score 6):

While typically `#error` is sufficient (and portable), there are times when you want to use a `pragma`, namely, when you want to optionally cause an error within a macro.

Here is an example use which depends on [C11's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) `_Generic` and `_Pragma`.

This example ensures `var` isn't an `int *` or a `short *`, but not a `const int *` at compile time.

Example:

```
#define MACRO(var)  do {  \
    (void)_Generic(var,   \
          int       *: 0, \
          short     *: 0, \
          const int *: 0 _Pragma("GCC error \"const not allowed\""));  \
    \
    MACRO_BODY(var); \
} while (0)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#pragma GCC error "error message"
```

Ref: *[7 Pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
#pragma GCC error "my message"
```

But it is not standard.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `static_assert`:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER < 1916
    static_assert(false, "MSVC supported versions are 1916 and later");
#endif
```