# preprocessing directives to prevent a project from release and debug symbols

Tags: preprocessor

Is there anyway to restrict by using pre-processing directives to prevent a project from compiling when both the Release and Debug symbols are defined?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming C/C++:

```
#if defined (Debug) && defined (Release)
  #error Debug and Release are both defined !
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124968/gcc-pragma-to-stop-compilation). According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8tk0xsk%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) it works in VC++ as well.