# How to make 'gcc -E' stop on #error

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to make GCC's preprocessor stop when it finds a #error, when running it with option `-E`?

For instance, in the following program:

```
#error STOP HERE
int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

Running `gcc` on this program results in an interrupted compilation at line 1, but running `gcc -E` outputs the same line, and then continues with preprocessing.

Note: my question is similar to [GCC #pragma to stop compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124968/gcc-pragma-to-stop-compilation), but concerning the `-E` flag, so maybe both should be merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. Processor directives (e.g. #error ) are used to give commands to the compiler. By using the -E option the compiler never runs, so it doesn't have a reason to stop. The -E flag is design to print all the code that gets compiled with your program without actually compiling.