# How can I invoke a compile-time error via a C++ macro?

Tags: c++, macros, compiler-errors

The idea is to cause a compile-time error with an error message if a certain macro is *invoked*. Can this be done? How?

```
#ifdef RUBBISH_COMPILER
#  define alignof(T)  // what here?
#endif

const std::size_t = alignof(some_type);  // invocation, causing compilation error
```

The invocation shall produce a sensible error message like 
*alignof() not available with this compiler*.

Comment: Are you using gcc? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124968/gcc-pragma-to-stop-compilation

Comment: @CompuChip No, that's not what I want.

Answer (score 4):

In C++11,

```
#define DONT_INVOKE_ME static_assert(false, "Don't invoke this macro");
```

Historically, it was easy to cause an error, but trickier to get a message into the output. One simple trick was to create an invalid declaration, with the message in the declared name:

```
#define DONT_INVOKE_ME char dont_invoke_this_macro[-1];
```

This isn't perfect, as you can't use freeform text for the message - it must be a valid identifier. There were fancier tricks (such as those used by Boost's static assert), but they're only of historical interest these days.

Comment: Hmm. That assumes that the macro is expanded in a context where `static_assert()` is allowed.

Comment: @Walter: `static_assert` is treated as a declaration, and allowed (just about) anywhere.

Comment: In contexts where an expression is expected it can be useful to wrap static_assert() in a block, e.g. #define UNUSABLE_VALUE { _Static_assert (false, "bad value"); }.  This is maybe only a good idea in contexts where the clients are known, e.g. when the macro is a tuple designed for consumption by known other macros.