# How can I programmatically force the compiler to stop the compilation process after it encountered a user created error?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

In my code I am using the `#error` preprocessor directive in order to create an error. However, it still continues the building process.

How can I force the building process **programmatically** to stop after encountering my error?

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, C++ v140, x86, for Windows 10.

Comment: [StopOnFirstBuildError](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/91aaa139-5d3c-43a7-b39f-369196a84fa5)?

Comment: I am specifically searching a solution to do this `programmatically`.

Comment: What do you mean by *programmatically*? In the code? Via external scripting?

Comment: Something like `#stop` to stop compiling after a certain `#if` statement was true. Not using a plugin for Visual Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCC #pragma to stop compilation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124968/gcc-pragma-to-stop-compilation)

Comment: @cad: OP knows about `#error` and also isn't asking about GCC.

Comment: `#error` is exactly meant for this. Could you be more specific in what is happening to your build?

Comment: `#error` terminates compilation of the current translation unit (source file). It doesn't necessarily stop an IDE from continuing to compile other sources files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**From MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8tk0xsk.aspx)

> The #error directive emits a user-specified error message at compile time ***and then terminates the compilation.***

*(Emphasis Added)*

If compilation is continuing after the `#error` directive, then you're doing something odd, or MSVC is broken.